# ArcPy AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FromGeohash'

Tags: python, gis, arcpy, geohashing

I'm trying to use FromGeohash method in Arcpy but it is failing.  Here's my code:

```
import arcpy
spatial_reference = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
print spatial_reference
extent = arcpy.FromGeohash('9q8yyx')
```

It's giving me the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/ArcGIS10.7/Scripts/Geohash_Converter.py", line 4, in <module>
    extent = arcpy.FromGeohash('9q8yyx')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FromGeohash'
```

Can anyone tell me what's causing this?  Arcpy seems to have been imported correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the FromGeohash function is only available in the ArcPro version of ArcPy. With the ArcMap version (10.6) if I try to import that I get an error:

```
from arcpy import FromGeohash

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name FromGeohash
```

Also the only documentation I can find for FromGeohash is for ArcGIS Pro. The only mention of Geohash I can find in the ArcMap documentation is for the [Data Interoperability extension](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/data-interoperability/supported-formats-with-the-data-interoperability-extension.htm).

So it looks like you will either need to use the ArcGIS Pro python interpreter or else use a different module for decoding the geohash. It looks like this [Python module](https://github.com/vinsci/geohash) might work?